# showing an element on hover, using first element ID as variable in targetting second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Basically I have two sets of elements. for example:

```
<ul id="feature1">
    <li class="items" id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="items" id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="items" id="item3">Item 3</li>
<ul>

<ul id="feature2">
    <li class="post" id="item1-post">Post 1</li>
    <li class="post" id="item2-post">Post 2</li>
    <li class="post" id="item3-post">Post 3</li>  
<ul>
```

What I'm attempting to do here is fairly simple: When the user hovers over an element from `#feature1`, I show (and then hide on mouseout) the corresponding element in `#feature2`. I could write functions for each `.items` element and it's corresponding `.post` element but I'm thinking it should be possible, with the right naming scheme, to write this as a single function by first getting the `id` of the hovered on `.items` element, then applying the show/hide (or adding class, whatever) by looking for the right `.post` element with the saved ID `variable + "-post"`.

To simplify: I mouse over `li#item1` - jQuery saves `#item1` as my variable, and then looks for a child of `#feature2` with the id of `item1 + "-post"`, showing the given element, and then hiding it on mouseout.

I've come very close, but can never seem to figure out the right logic.

If this is doable, the second aspect I'm looking to accomplish is an additional `onclick` that keeps the corresponding `#feature2` element displayed until mouseover of the next element.

Thanks ahead of time for the help, I've been banging my head against this one all afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, albeit untested:

```
$('#feature1 li.items').hover(function(){
    $('#' + this.id + '-post').show();
}, function(){
    $('#' + this.id + '-post').hide();
});
```

Or:

```
$('#feature1 li.items').hover(function(){
    $('li.post').eq($(this).index()).show();
}, function(){
    $('li.post').eq($(this).index()).hide();
});
```

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Worked like a charm - even more elegant than i thought it'd be. One further question, is it possible to include an onclick to freeze the "shown" element, until the next element is moused over?

Comment: @user16111 instead of continuing this thread, why don't you ask a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Without naming scheme using corresponding indexes

```
var $feature2 = $('#feature2'),
    $hoveredElm;

$('#feature1 li').hover(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $hoveredElm = $feature2.find('li').eq(idx).show();
}, function(){
    $hoveredElm.hide();
});
```

Comment: This is a step ahead of where i'm at with jQuery, thanks for the notes - i'll give this a shot as well.